# Is it possible to download window in JS?

Tags: javascript, download, window, document

I would like to see the code of the browser object `window` in javascript. How exactly could I find this and find other things like module.exports and document, stuff already defined in the browser. I am just curious to see the code, not hacking anything. :)

Comment: Built-in APIs like that aren't written in JavaScript. [Here's the source code from Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master), you'll find their implementation in their somewhere. I hope you're ready to pick through a lot of C/C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the developer tools available in all modern browsers. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) is a starting point

Comment: This shows me the JS in a project. I want window objects, not objects defined on a website. But I can try it out.